# Conditional reordering in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The requirement is to order patient records by record date, unless they are the same patient based on one of three columns and then they should be grouped together. Furthermore, the matching priority is UID, MRN, SSN so if a patient has matching UIDs, group them together, otherwise if they have matching MRNs group them together, otherwise if they have matching SSNs group them together. Empty strings or nulls should be considered non-matched.

Example

| Record Date | Patient UID | Patient MRN | Patient SSN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 1 | ABC | 111111111 |
| 02/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 03/01/2023 | 2 | DEF | 222222222 |
| 04/01/2023 | 1 |  |  |
| 05/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 06/01/2023 | 2 |  |  |
| 07/01/2023 |  | ABC |  |
| 08/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 09/01/2023 |  | DEF |  |
| 10/01/2023 |  |  | 111111111 |
| 11/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 12/01/2023 |  |  | 222222222 |

Should sort as

| Record Date | Patient UID | Patient MRN | Patient SSN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 1 | ABC | 111111111 |
| 04/01/2023 | 1 |  |  |
| 07/01/2023 |  | ABC |  |
| 10/01/2023 |  |  | 111111111 |
| 02/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 03/01/2023 | 2 | DEF | 222222222 |
| 06/01/2023 | 2 |  |  |
| 09/01/2023 |  | DEF |  |
| 12/01/2023 |  |  | 222222222 |
| 05/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 08/01/2023 |  |  |  |
| 11/01/2023 |  |  |  |

This groups the two patients together keeping the date order both within the groups and outside the groups.

I was hoping that something like this would be sufficient, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cases
ORDER BY MIN(RecordDate) OVER(partition by NULLIF(UID, ''), NULLIF(MRN, ''), NULLIF(SSN, '')), RecordDate
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Fiddle available at https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=54d03ca0-8a23-4d83-a970-ccecd9fedb6d

Comment: Slight detour...I sure hope that SSN field is not the social security number. If it is it should not be in clear text.

Comment: And this is a problem in 2 parts, first identifying rows that are essentially the same person, and then ordering by them.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will always be one complete record with all 3 columns filled in?

Comment: Why is 02/01/2024 ordered the way it is? If that's supposed to be 02/01/2023 makes sense, but I can't figure the reasoning as 02/01/2024.

Comment: @DaleK No, there will be records with none of the three filled in.

Comment: @Error_2646 It was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Well clearly when none are filled in, there is nothing you can do. But could you get a record with just the Patient MRN for example? Without there being a second record with the same Patient MRN and a UID?

Comment: Your match conditions as stated appear to be neither *reflexive* nor *transitive*.
Consider three records `A(xxx, 222, 333)`, `B(111, 222, yyy)`, and `C(111, zzz, 333)`.
A matches B on MRN, but does not match C.
B matches C on UID, but since MRN is not considered, it does not match A.
C matches B on UID, but since SSN is not considered, it does not match A.
So we have A matches B, but not B matches A (not reflexive).
We also have A matches B and B matches C, but not A matches C (not transitive).
Without some modifications to the grouping criteria, we do not have a well-defined grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a stab at it. Note this assumes 02/01/2024 was a typo in the original sample and should be 02/01/2023. Please add some more detail on the rationale of that if it's not a typo.

Explanation: The sequence of `coalesce( (select yada from ... where patientUID condition ), ..., (select yada from ... where patientSSN condition ))` goes through the precedence to assign all like patients the same fuzzy_id. This is used to partition for the ordering later.

Then the absolute_order_by_record_date is a bit clunky. Basically for records with all null/no fuzzy match found we need to partition on something unique so the nulls don't all get lumped together. The (-1) is just to prevent any collisions with fuzzy_match so we can coalesce() when partitioning without them bleeding together.

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZsHrUiSR

```
CREATE TABLE PatientData (
    RecordDate DATE NOT NULL,
    PatientUID INT,
    PatientMRN VARCHAR(50),
    PatientSSN VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO PatientData (RecordDate, PatientUID, PatientMRN, PatientSSN) VALUES
    ('2023-01-01', 1, 'ABC', '111111111'),
    ('2023-02-01', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2023-03-01', 2, 'DEF', '222222222'),
    ('2023-04-01', 1, NULL, NULL),
    ('2023-05-01', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2023-06-01', 2, NULL, NULL),
    ('2023-07-01', NULL, 'ABC', NULL),
    ('2023-08-01', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2023-09-01', NULL, 'DEF', NULL),
    ('2023-10-01', NULL, NULL, '111111111'),
    ('2023-11-01', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2023-12-01', NULL, NULL, '222222222');

with precedence_match as (
select *,
       -- negative is just to prevent collisions with fuzzy_match
       (-1)*row_number() over (
         partition by 1 
             order by RecordDate) absolute_order_by_record_date,
       coalesce(
         (
         select max(t2.PatientUID)
           from PatientData t2
          where t1.PatientUID = t2.PatientUID
         ),
         (
         select max(t2.PatientUID)
           from PatientData t2
          where t1.PatientMRN = t2.PatientMRN
         ),
         (
         select max(t2.PatientUID)
           from PatientData t2
          where t1.PatientSSN = t2.PatientSSN
         ),
         t1.PatientUID
       ) as fuzzy_match
  from PatientData t1)
select RecordDate,
       PatientUID,
       PatientMRN,
       PatientSSN,
       min(RecordDate) over ( 
         partition by coalesce(fuzzy_match,absolute_order_by_record_date)) as calculated_min_date_for_reference
  from precedence_match
 order 
    by min(RecordDate) over ( 
         partition by coalesce(fuzzy_match,absolute_order_by_record_date)),
       RecordDate;
```

| RecordDate | PatientUID | PatientMRN | PatientSSN | calculated_min_date_for_reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | ABC | 111111111 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-04-01 | 1 | null | null | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-07-01 | null | ABC | null | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-10-01 | null | null | 111111111 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-02-01 | null | null | null | 2023-02-01 |
| 2023-03-01 | 2 | DEF | 222222222 | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2 | null | null | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-09-01 | null | DEF | null | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-12-01 | null | null | 222222222 | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-05-01 | null | null | null | 2023-05-01 |
| 2023-08-01 | null | null | null | 2023-08-01 |
| 2023-11-01 | null | null | null | 2023-11-01 |

Answer (score 0):

**BLUF:** This approach simulates a patients table. It will fail, if there are instances where all three ID's are not used at least once. A more complex logic for populating this "patients" table could be used. However, I would use Error_2646 approach before getting more complex.

**DATA**

```
if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cases') is not null)
    drop table #Cases

CREATE TABLE #Cases 
(
    RecordDate DATE,
    UID nvarchar(255),
    MRN nvarchar(255),
    SSN nvarchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #Cases
VALUES
('01/01/2023', 1   , 'ABC', '111111111'),
('02/01/2023', null, null,  null),
('03/01/2023', 2   , 'DEF', '222222222'),
('04/01/2023', 1   , null,  null),
('05/01/2023', null, null,  null),
('06/01/2023', 2   , null,  null),
('07/01/2023', null, 'ABC', null),
('08/01/2023', null, null,  null),
('09/01/2023', null, 'DEF', null),
('10/01/2023', null, null,  '111111111'),
('11/01/2023', null, null,  null),
('12/01/2023', null, null,  '222222222');
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  
    c.RecordDate,
    c.UID [Patient UID],
    c.MRN [Patient MRN],
    c.SSN [Patient SSN]
FROM #Cases c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        UID,
        MRN,
        SSN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [UID]) orderId,
        MIN(RecordDate) AS MinRecordDate
    FROM #Cases
    WHERE UID IS NOT NULL 
      AND MRN IS NOT NULL
      AND SSN IS NOT NULL   
    GROUP BY UID, MRN, SSN
) p ON p.UID = c.UID OR p.MRN = c.MRN OR p.SSN = c.SSN
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE (p.MinRecordDate, c.RecordDate),
    ISNULL(p.orderId, 9223372036854775807)
```

The left join sub query simulates the "patients" table (or clients or.. whatever you call people) and matches any case on the three possible reference ID's that can be used. It grabs the min(RecordDate) and assigns an orderId for sorting the final results. The order by uses the MinRecordDate/RecordDate dates and then the order by the clients within that date.

**Results**

| RecordDate | Patient UID | Patient MRN | Patient SSN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | ABC | 111111111 |
| 2023-04-01 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-07-01 | NULL | ABC | NULL |
| 2023-10-01 | NULL | NULL | 111111111 |
| 2023-02-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-03-01 | 2 | DEF | 222222222 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-09-01 | NULL | DEF | NULL |
| 2023-12-01 | NULL | NULL | 222222222 |
| 2023-05-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-08-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2023-11-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Other Thoughts: If you have a patients table with the ID's that they may be referenced by, the query would be simplified, run faster, and still work regardless if the patient had 1, 2, or 3 reference ID's. Likewise, if there is a PatientId, the query could again be simplified. This however would require a trigger or some other business logic rule to apply the PatientId to the cases table on a save using one of the reference ID's.

For Example:

```
LEFT JOIN #patients p ON p.UID = c.UID OR p.MRN = c.MRN OR p.SSN = c.SSN
-- or
LEFT JOIN #patients p ON p.PatientId = c.PatientId
```